# Is it possible to have both jQueryUI and Mootools running at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, mootools

I want to use both jQueryUI and Mootools in my app but only the last one entered into the javascript_include_tag in my layout will work. Is it possible to have both running at the same time?

Im using the accordian from Mootools and the buttons from jQueryUI.

Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably best to stick with just one library (there's an accordion available for jQuery as well, in UI as well I guess). But if you want to use both, you can use jQuery's noconflict mode. Read all about it here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/